# Unreal Engine 4 зависает через некоторое время

Tags: unreal-engine-4

Только начинаю работать с UE и сразу сталкиваюсь с проблемой.

Запускаю UE на своём ноутбуке (Intel Core i5 8265U, Intel UHD Graphics 620, 8 Gb RAM, SSD, к ноутбуку подкинут монитор и "клава-мышь"(других вариантов работать, пока что, нет)), создаю проект из шаблона (FPS). Всё загружается и работает, только наглухо зависает через некоторое время. Обнаруженные моменты зависания: запуск сцены/уровня или через некоторое время после запуска; если выйти из Viewport (Shift+F1) и подождать некоторое время (менять настройки или просто ничего не трогать), создание нового уровня/сцены (больше продвинуться на смог из-за зависаний). Попытки убить процесс заканчиваются тем, что Windows 10 вешается (картинка зависает, только курсор движется). Не важно, что запущено совместно с UE. Были испробованы UE 4.24 - 4.26, но безуспешно. Пробовал совместимость с Win 7 (были и такие варианты решения проблем), она не помогла. Уже собранный на другом PC проект запускается и спокойно работает. Полгода назад пробовал запустить проект на версии 4.24 и такой проблемы не было. Сейчас пришла в голову идея сменить драйвер видеокарты.

Драйверы версий:

- 26.20.100.7463
- 26.20.100.8141 (выкидывает репорт и наглухо зависает)
- 27.20.100.8935
- 27.20.100.9030
  не решают проблему.

Comment: встройка интел и малый объем оперативной памяти - залог проблем

Comment: Проблему решает отключение автоскрытия панели задачи в Win 10. Эту тему можно закрывать.